# kill process on external script run as a service

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-scripting

I've setup a linux (CentOS) service to run a script that runs in the backgroud (`daemon /home/user/testftp.sh &`) or in the context of the start and stop service:

```
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

prog=ftpmonitor
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/ftpmonitor

start() {
        [ "$EUID" != "0" ] && exit 4

        # Start daemons.
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        daemon /home/user/testftp.sh &
        PID1=$!
        #echo "$PID1"
        RETVAL=$?
        echo

        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
        return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
        [ "$EUID" != "0" ] && exit 4
        echo -n $"Shutting down $prog: "
        killproc $prog
        kill $PID1
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
        return $RETVAL
}
```

My problem is stopping all the processes. `killproc $prog` will stop the service but the background process is still running (`testftp.sh`), which needs to be run in the backgroud to monitor ftp logs).

I've seen similar posts that say to use `PID1=$!` which would represent the PID for `testftp.sh`. But the PID seems to just be the service `ftpmonitor`. So obviously my stop service command with `kill $PID1` will not work.

**EDIT**:

testftp.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo tail -F /var/log/vsftpd.log | while read line; do
  if sudo echo "$line" | grep -q 'OK UPLOAD:'; then
    username=$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f8 | sed 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/')
    filename=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2 | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -d '"')
    home="/home/vsftpd/$username"
    if sudo ls "$home$filename" &> /dev/null; then
      # do something with $filename
        echo "$home$filename is the file to be proccesed"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to kill it using one or all of these:

- `killall testftp.sh`
- `kill $(pgrep testftp.sh)`
- `pkill testftp.sh`

If your script is launching other processes and you want to kill it and all its children, use `pkill -P`:

```
-P ppid,... 
    Only match processes whose parent process ID is listed.
```

So, instead of `kill $PID1`, use

```
pkill -P $PID1
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
kill -- -$(ps opgid= $PID)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes) on SO has some nice pointers.